# Create an NSPredicate with a line break as part of a string

Tags: swift, newline, nspredicate

I need to create a predicate that will look for the following string:

"fred\n5" where \n is a newline.

At least, this is string that is returned when reading the metadata back

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Regular Expression

```
let string = """
    fred
    5
    """

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self MATCHES %@", "fred\\n5")
predicate.evaluate(with: string) // true
```

It's also possible to use the pattern `fred(\\n|\\r)5`, it considers both linefeed **and** return.

---

Alternatively remove the newline character (actually any whitespace and newline characters)

```
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Thank you. That confirms my thinking. Can I just ask if you could give me any more pointers on how to untangle this: NSPredicate(format: "%K MATCHES %@", NSMetadataItemFinderTagsKey, "\\w+\\\n\\d"). What I want is all URLs that contain the last numeric character

Comment: Anything with a trailing numeric character is `.+\\d$`